# Tkinter 'Button' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create an application that'll convert Inches to CM and vice versa, however when I press the button that has the function bound to it to grab the user's input from a entry box to do the proper calculations on it, I get an error that says a `Button` object is not callable.

I've already looked at many fixes on here that have the same sort of error but instead with the `Button` is replaced with something else, however the solutions for those questions were just because they named variables the same thing as actual Tkinter objects. It doesn't seem to me that I made that same mistake but I might just be burnt out and never noticed it.

```py
from tkinter import *


# Create the window
root = Tk()

root.geometry("270x90")

# Text
cmText = Label(root, text = "CM:")
cmText.grid(row=1,column=1)
cmText.config(font=("Arial", 11))

inchText = Label(root, text = "  IN:")
inchText.grid(row=3,column=1)
inchText.config(font=("Arial", 11))

# Label
equal = Label(root,text="=")
equal.grid(row=2,column=2)

# Entry Boxes
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row=1,column=2)

entry2 = Entry(root)
entry2.grid(row=3, column=2)

# Functions
def quitFunc(event):
    root.destroy()

def inchConvert(event):
    inchVar = float(entry2.get())
    cm = inchVar * 2.54
    entry1.insert(0,cm)

# Buttons
inchConvert = Button(root,text="▲")
inchConvert.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=2)
inchConvert.bind("<Button-1>",inchConvert)

cmConvert = Button(root,text="▼")
cmConvert.grid(row=1,column=3, padx=5,pady=2)

clear = Button(root,text=" C ")
clear.grid(row=2,column=5,ipadx=5)

quitButton = Button(root,text="Quit")
quitButton.grid(row=2,column=6, padx=10)
quitButton.bind("<Button-1>",quitFunc)

# Main Processing Loop
root.mainloop()
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable
```

Normally what should happen is that the `cm` variable would be inserted into the top entry box (`entry1`) when I click the Up Arrow button, but instead I get an error when I press it.

Comment: You are assigning the button object to inchConvert and then passing inchConvert as function. Renaming either the function or the button variable should fix it.

Comment: As @wastl says, you have two different things assigned to the name `inchConvert` initially it's a function, but then you change it into a tkinter `Button`. You need to rename one of them. You also need to learn how to the the `command=` option that tkinter `Button` widgets support—it will make your program easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fixed code. The problem is that the button and the method share the same name. I renamed it and it worked.

```
from tkinter import *

# Create the window
root = Tk()

root.geometry("270x90")

def inchConvert_rename():
     inchVar = float(entry2.get())
     cm = inchVar * 2.54
     entry1.insert(0,cm)

# Buttons
**inchConvert = Button(root,text="▲",command= lambda: inchConvert_rename())**
inchConvert.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=2)

# Main Processing Loop
root.mainloop()
```

If you care about events I find this works:

```
inchConvert.bind("<Button-1>",lambda x: inchConvert_rename(x))
```